# Why do we need file -> private_data?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm currently learning linux device drivers and can't understand one moment from basic character device driver code.

```
struct scull_pipe {
       ...
};

static struct scull_pipe *scull_devices;
```

```
static int scull_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    struct scull_pipe *dev;

    dev = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct scull_pipe, cdev);
    filp->private_data = dev;
    ...
}
```

```
static ssize_t scull_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count,
                loff_t *f_pos)
{
    struct scull_pipe *dev = filp->private_data;
    ...
    if (copy_from_user(dev->wp, buf, count)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

My question is why do we need to use `scull_devices` from `filp->private_data` instead of directly referencing `scull_devices` object?

Comment: Did you take into account that there might be multiple instances of a device driver? Would using a global variable still work then?

Comment: I thought about that, but don't we get the same instance of `scull_pipe` when we take it from inode by `container_of`?

Comment: Do you expect to get same inode for different devices? I am not so deep in device drivers but I don't expect to get same data when opening `/dev/tty0` vs `/dev/tty1`.

Comment: Is `scull_devices` a single struct or an array of structs?

Comment: Forgot that we can have several devices controled by one module, now it seems clear. Thank you!

Comment: For multiple devices, it is more convenient and faster to use `filp->private_data` than to look up the private data pointer corresponding to the inode's `i_rdev` value, particularly since most of the file operation handler functions do not have a parameter pointing to the inode directly and need to get it from `file_inode(filp)`.